How to install node-debug? node-debug: command not found
after looking at some tutorials I tried to run node-debug
node-debug node_modules/@aws-sdk/client-s3
node-debug: command not found

I installed npm i debug,but that is other module.
How to run node debugging from the console?

https://github.com/node-inspector/node-inspector

The node-debug command was provided by the node-inspector package, which has been deprecated. For debugging Node.js applications, the built-in Node.js debugger or modern tools like Chrome DevTools are now recommended.
